# Pytest failing on file open command string assert - what's the best way to test this?

Tags: python-requests, pytest

I am constructing a command to pass to requests library to Post an attachment - as in
**files= attachment = {"attachment": ("image.png", open("C:\tmp\sensor.png", "rb"), "image/png")}**

The code is working but I cannot get PyTest to test it as -is because of the open command which is executed when evaluated.  Here is simplified code of the problem

```
import pytest

def openfile():
    cmd = {"cmd": open(r"C:\tmp\sensor.png")}
    return cmd


def test_openfile():
    cmd = openfile()

    #assert str(cmd) == str({"cmd": open(r"C:\tmp\sensor.png")})  # this works

    assert cmd == {"cmd": open(r"C:\tmp\sensor.png")}            # this does not
```

PyTest complains that the two side are different but then confirms they are the same in the diff panel!

**Expected :{'cmd': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\tmp\sensor.png' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>}**

**Actual   :{'cmd': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\tmp\sensor.png' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>}**

**'Click to see difference'**   -  Opening  diff panel reports 'Contents are identical'!

I can just stick with comparing the generated string with expected string but am wondering if there is a better way to do this.
Ideas?

Comment: Well, you get different objects from the different open calls, so they are different. But you don't want to compare the `TextIOWarpper` objects, but their contents. Or maybe not the contents, but the signature of the call.

Comment: Yes I want to compare the signature of the call so casting to string does validate my code but it seems a bit of a hack which is why I am asking if there is a better way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code: in `openfile`, you load an icon and return a dict with that icon as value - I would think you want to return the function pointer instead to execute the command later (at least this is what the test suggests), or am I wrong?

Comment: That is the format of the files= parameter that requests library needs to post an attachment. Example post from their docs:>>> files = {'file': ('report.xls', open('report.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the properties of the actual file buffer that is returned by the open call, instead of the references to that buffer, for example:

```py
def test_openfile():
    cmd = openfile()

    expected_filename = r"C:\tmp\sensor.png"
    assert "cmd" in cmd
    file_cmd = cmd["cmd"]
    assert file_cmd.name == expected_filename
    with open(expected_filename) as f:
        contents = f.read()
        assert file_cmd.read() == contents
```

Note that in a test you may not have the file contents, or have them in another place like a fixture, so testing the file contents may have to be adapted, or may not be needed, depending on what you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

After talking this through with a friend I think my original approach is perfectly valid. For anyone that trips over this question here's why:

I am trying to pytest building of an executable parameter to pass to another library for execution. The execution of the parameter is not relevant, just that it is correctly formatted. The test is to compare what is generated with the expected parameter ( as if I typed it) .
Therefore casting to string or json and comparing **is appropriate** since that is what a human does to manually check the code!

Comment: I agree that this is a valid approach (though I wouldn't use it, as it could be a bit fragile regarding whitespace), but I would at least say that a computer can do _more_ then a human that manually checks the code :)